# How can I get the value of nested JSON array in Ionic?

Tags: arrays, json, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I am trying to display nested list. I am using JSON response from the server to get all the values. This is my server response.

```
{
    "addonCategories": [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Cooking type",
            "parent_id": 0,
            "product_category": 10,
            "selection": "single",
            "type": "other",
            "order": null,
            "shows_selection": true,
            "selection_type": true,
            "direct_pricing": false,
            "is_size": false,
            "addonItems": [
                {
                    "id": 725,
                    "name": "Lightly Done",
                    "product_id": 0,
                    "addon_category_id": 24,
                    "price": 0,
                    "image": "",
                    "attribute": null,
                    "main_category_id": 24,
                    "half_image": null,
                    "full_image": null,
                    "order": null,
                    "large_price": "",
                    "description": null,
                    "default_sauce": 0,
                    "restaurants_id": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 723,
                    "name": "Regular",
                    "product_id": 0,
                    "addon_category_id": 24,
                    "price": 0,
                    "image": "",
                    "attribute": null,
                    "main_category_id": 24,
                    "half_image": null,
                    "full_image": null,
                    "order": null,
                    "large_price": "",
                    "description": null,
                    "default_sauce": 0,
                    "restaurants_id": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 724,
                    "name": "Well Done",
                    "product_id": 0,
                    "addon_category_id": 24,
                    "price": 0,
                    "image": "",
                    "attribute": null,
                    "main_category_id": 24,
                    "half_image": null,
                    "full_image": null,
                    "order": null,
                    "large_price": "",
                    "description": null,
                    "default_sauce": 0,
                    "restaurants_id": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using following HTML code to display nested list with checkbox selection.

```
<ion-list class="setting-content">
<ion-list-header *ngFor="let item of (addonDetail | async)?.addonCategories" no-lines>{{item.name}}
          <ion-item-group class="fst-group">
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item1 of item.addonItems" no-lines>
            <ion-label >{{item1.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox (click)="clickAddon(item1)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
          </ion-item-group>
      </ion-list-header>
</ion-list>
```

So how can I get the `name`s from inner JSON array `addonItems`?

When I run the code it gives me the names from main array (`addonCategories`) but not from the inner one (`addonItems`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the structure of your HTML template - in short, when you have an `ion-list-header`, it attempts to render the text for that header in an `ion-label`. The presence of your nested `ion-label` (within your `ion-item`) thus breaks the template.

Instead, and per the Ionic documentation here, your `ion-list-header` should not contain any child `ion-item` elements: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/#advanced

If instead you restructure your HTML template like this, it will work:

```
<ion-list class="setting-content">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of addonCategories">
    <ion-list-header no-lines>{{item.name}}</ion-list-header>
    <ion-item-group class="fst-group">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let addOn of item.addonItems" no-lines>
        <ion-label>{{addOn.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (click)="clickAddon(addOn)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

Notice on line 3 that the `ion-list-header` is opened & closed.

Because of the need for nested `*ngFor` directives - which I'm guessing is why you tried to embed your `ion-item` elements in the header - I've used the `ng-container` instead. This way, you can still iterate through each "header" item's array of nested `addonItems`.

Working Plnkr here: https://embed.plnkr.co/RSd1MdmajLxpdZmTHk8J/

Comment: Hi @Stevangelista, It worked like a charm and your working example is the best. Great work.